# Firebase crashlytics not building even when downgrading versions

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library, crashlytics, firebase-performance

We're using Firebase in our app and while we are still on **Support library 28** Not AndoridX.
i have managed to add Analytics and Performance monitoring and they work fine after researching the suitable versions that are compatible with support-lib 28.

Now i'm trying to add crashlytics and i'm getting build errors with each lib version starting from *17.0.0* going down all the way to *2.9.8*

with 2.9.8 it get :

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:2.9.8
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

with 17.0.0 i get:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase- 
crashlytics:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.CrashlyticsExtension_Decorated
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

My project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }
    ext {

        firebaseAnalytics = "16.3.0" //Firebase SDK for Google Analytics compatible with support lib
        firebasePerformanceMonitoring = "17.0.2" //Firebase SDK for performance monitoring compatible with support lib
        firebaseCrashlytics = "17.0.0" //Firebase Crashlytics
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0' // Crashlytics Gradle plugin.

    }
}

allprojects {

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

app module build.gradle dependencies block:

```
dependencies {

      def supportLib_version = "28.0.0"

      implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLib_version"
      implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLib_version"
      implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLib_version"

       ........


      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:$firebaseAnalytics"
      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$firebasePerformanceMonitoring"
      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:$firebaseCrashlytics"
   }
```

While some might suggest that we migrate the project to AndroidX, this is a big project with many libraries and i'm not the only developer working on it, hence that won't be feasible IMT

Comment: Have you tried to do apply plugin: 'io.fabric' inside your build.gradle(App)

Comment: @JimmyFlash Sorry, totally I mistook your post.

Comment: @hata no problems, i just wish i could have FB-crashlytics implemented the way i managed to implement analytics and performance monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Fabric/Firebaser here - I think that overall there is some incorrect versioning and dependency integration in this project that is causing issues.

You will unfortunately not be able to use Firebase Crashlytics until you upgrade to Android X, as it is a dependency for the Firebase Crashlytics SDK [as described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android#before_you_begin).

You can still use the legacy Fabric Crashlytics SDK in Firebase however, and you can find the instructions for that here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android. I recommend taking out whatever Crashlytics setup you've attempted to integrate so far and follow the instructions there. For what it's worth, it looks like you're getting the versioning wrong, as this version does not exist:

`com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:2.9.8`

firebase-crashltyics only has versions like 17.0.0 and upward. 2.9.8 is a version of our aforementioned legacy Fabric Crashlytics SDK, so you're looking to use something like this:

`com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello @kevin, regarding the legacy sdk, we were using Fabric crashlytics before but we ran into build failure issues when we upgraded android studio 3.6 with gradle plugin v3.6.0,  the Fabric plugin(1.2) was the cause, so we decided to remove and adopt FB Analytics with Perf monitoring and FB crashlytics, all worked except crashlytics. My concern is that since the legacy SDK is longer maintained it could cause same or similar issues with future AS / gradle, we always keep those updated to the latest.

Comment: Then I definitely recommend using this doc to get started with Crashlytics and making sure that you have the right setup according to this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android. Since future updates to support newer versions of Gradle and Android Studio will only be pushed for the new Crashlytics SDK, it sounds like this is the best path for you.

Comment: I believe in the end that's the right choice since there's also a note in the link you sent  "Note: The Fabric SDK is now deprecated and will continue reporting your app's crashes until November 15, 2020. On this date, the Fabric SDK and old versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDK will stop sending crashes for your app. To continue getting crash reports in the Firebase console, make sure you upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK versions 17.0.0+". Thank you for your help.